# JavaScript document outlining in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008

**Problem/Questions:**

Document outlining for JavaScript files is not working in Visual Studio 2008. Is this still supported? If so, how do I enable it?

If it's not supported, are there any free plugins that provide similar functionality?

**Notes:**

- This used to work for me in Visual studio 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found, and installed the following and it works well!

http://scriptoutline.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's very frustrating for those of us that use javascript heavily.  Try this: http://blog.devarchive.net/2008/04/using-region-directive-with-javascript.html

You have to add regions ("//#region") in your code, but then the macro will make the regions collapsable.

An other option is to highlight some code and the do CTRL M+H.  This will outline the highlighted code, allowing you to expand and collapse the code.  Unfortunately, the outlining will be lost when you close the doc.